# Registering Silex Providers Throwing Errors

Tags: service, silex, provider

Creating an App in Silex and trying to take the first few steps, one of which is setting up my services/providers.

I am currently loading these using a YAML file. I have also tried registering each individual like the docs say e.g.

```
$this->register( new TwigServiceProvider(),array() );
```

Here is my current bootstrap file(loading services from a file):

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Igorw\Silex\ConfigServiceProvider;
use Silex\Application as Silex;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


class Bootstrap extends Silex
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this['debug'] = true;

        $this->registerDefaultParameters();
        $this->registerDefaultServices();
        $this->registerRoutes();

    }

    protected function registerDefaultParameters()
    {
        $paths = isset($this['base_path']) ? $this['base_path'] : array();

        if (!isset($paths['base'])) {
            $paths['base'] = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../');
        }

        $defaults = array(
            'config' => $paths['base'] . '/App/Config',
            'twig.path' => $paths['base'] . '/public/themes/base/templates'
        );

        foreach ($defaults as $key => $value) {
            if (!isset($paths[$key])) {
                $paths[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        $this['paths'] = $paths;
    }

    protected function registerDefaultServices()
    {
        $this->register( new ConfigServiceProvider($this['paths']['config'] . "/Services.yml") );

        foreach($this['services'] as $serviceName => $serviceData)
        {
            $this->register( new $serviceData['class'],(array_key_exists('parameters',$serviceData)) ? $serviceData['parameters'] : array() );
        }

    }

    protected function registerRoutes()
    {
        $this->register( new ConfigServiceProvider($this['paths']['config'] . "/Routes.yml") );

        $collection = new RouteCollection();
        foreach($this['routes'] as $key => $value)
        {
            $collection->add( $key, new Route(
                $value['path'],
                $value['defaults'],
                array(),
                array(),
                null,
                null,
                $value['methods']
            ));
        }

        $this['routes'] = $collection;
    }
}
```

My issue is:

With every provider i am receiving fatal errors like

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Identifier "this_is_an_identifier" is not defined.'

I'm receiving this errors loading the services from a file and manually. and its different for each provider e.g.

The error related to the twig provider is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Identifier "request_error" is not defined.'

Another one relating to Monolog is :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Identifier "dispatcher" is not defined.

So its like every provider/service has something wrong which obviously isn't the case. So my question is why am i continuously receiving these errors? from what i can see im not doing anything wrong?

Heres my composer file just in case it's a version thing:

```
    {
    "name": "cranbri/cvcms",
    "description": "Cranbri CV CMS Silex",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "1.2.2",
        "symfony/yaml": "2.6.1",
        "igorw/config-service-provider": "1.2.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4":{
            "App\\": "App/"
        }
    }
}
```

This is stopping my development altogether so if anyone can give me any details it will be much appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't calling parent!!! therefore i have none of the values the parent class did hence why many of the $app variables were not set and couldn't be found